# How to solve for the impulse response using a differential equation?

Tags: matlab, math, differential-equations

Given a differential equation:
`y[n] - 0.9y[n-1] + 0.81y[n-2] = x[n] - x[n-2]`

a. Find the impulse response for `h[n], n=0,1,2` using recursion.

b. Find the impulse response using MATLAB command filter.

Comment: This recursion is a **difference** equation, not a differential equation, as that would be formulated in terms of derivatives

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand that this is homework, so I will try to give you guidelines without actually giving away the answer completely:

### Using recursion

This is actually quite simple, because the differential equation contains the body of the recursive function almost entirely: y[n] = **0.9y[n-1]** - **0.81y[n-2]** + x[n] - x[n-2]

The parts in bold are actually the recursive calls! What you need to do is to build a function (let's call it `func`) that receives `x` and `n`, and calculates `y[n]`:

```
function y = func(x, n)
   if (n < 0)
      %# Handling for edge case n<0
      return 0
   else if (n == 0)
      %# Handling for edge case n=0
      return x(0)
   else
      %# The recursive loop
      return 0.9 * func(x, n-1) - 0.81 * func(x, n-2) + x(n) - x(n-2)
   end
```

Note that it's *pseudo-code*, so you still have to check the edge cases and deal with the indexation (indices in MATLAB start with 1 and not 0!).

### Using filters

The response of a digital filter is actually the y[n] that you're looking for. As you probably know from lesson, the coefficients of that filter would be the coefficients specified in the differential equation. MATLAB has a built-in function [`filter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/filter.html) that emulates just that, so if you write:

```
B = [1, 0, 1];        %# Coefficients for x
A = [1, 0.9, -0.81];  %# Coefficients for y
y = filter(B, A, x);
```

You'd get an output vector which holds all the values of y[n].

Comment: not sure your `A` or `B` is correct, but if this homework, I suggest you leave it as is.

Comment: If you're worried about the _signs_ of the elemenst, maybe you're right... I haven't put much thought into it, I wanted to leave something for the OP to solve :-).

Answer (score -1):

```
a=[1 -0.9 0.81]
b=[1 -1]
impz(b,a,50)
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code? As it looks completely different that the accepted answer, you should explain the difference such that others can learn from it